# To find the given limits from the graph

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

The questions asked are with respect to the given graph.

1) $\lim_{x\to0} \ln(1-f(x))$

2) $\lim_{x\to1^-} \ln(2+f(x))$

3) $\lim_{x\to1} (1-f(\ln x))$

4) $\lim_{x\to1^+} f(1- f(2-x))$

I wasn't sure as to how to go about solving these composite functions and I basically just substituted the value of $x$ first to solve the inner function and then went about solving the limit which I  understand is incorrect. Is there a particular formula or way to approach these kinds of problems? Any form of help an examples to illustrate maybe one of the question will be appreciated!

Comment: No, that is right sometimes. If $f$ is continuous at $L$ and $g(x)\rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow c$, then $f(g(x)) \rightarrow f(L)$ as $x \rightarrow c$

Comment: So if it's not continuous do you find the limits of each term inside the function as in, for the first one, will it be ln (lim(x->0) of 1 - lim(x->0) of f(x)) which would be ln(1-0) and the answer hence being 0? Is that the way to go about solving these composite functions if they are discontinuous ?

Comment: Good observation. First, 0 is the correct ans of the first one and you are doing it correctly.

Comment: I'm mainly having trouble with 4, could you maybe help me with that one? I'm not sure as to how to evaluate lim(x->1+) f(2-x)

Comment: you might not start analysis yet. In general, the limit might not exist, it plays safe to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits. You may refer to what I will write in the answer when you get to an analysis course.

Comment: The answer is 0 btw.

Comment: The given answer for question 4 is 1.

Comment: Yeah, I made a small computational error there.

Comment: The given answer is correct. See my long version of answer if you are interested.

Comment: I have double checked the calculus level answer. Note the order of logic. To invoke the change of variable, we indeed assumed the existence of the limit first. This assumption is validated as we found the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A calculus level answer**. This method takes the following as granted:

(1) [Continuous function] If $f$ is continuous at $L$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c^\pm}g(x) =L$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow c^\pm}(f\circ g)(x)=f(L)$ .

(2) [Change of variable] Suppose $h$ is strictly decreasing and continuous at $c$. If $\lim_{u \rightarrow h(c)^-} g(u) = M$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow c^+} g(h(x))=M$.

Then  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+} f(1-f(2-x)) = \lim_{2-x\rightarrow 1^-} f(1-f(2-x))= \lim_{u\rightarrow 1^-} f(1-f(u))$.

But $\lim_{u\rightarrow 1^-} 1-f(u) = 2$.

And $f$ is continuous at $2$. Therefore the required limit is $f(2) = 1$.

---

**An analysis level answer:** The rigorous definition of a $g(c+) = L$ is given below:

> For all positive number $\epsilon >0$, there is another positive number $\delta > 0$ such that for all real number $x$ where $g(x)$ is defined, 
>   $$\delta> x - c>0 \implies |g(x) - L| < \epsilon$$

Now we wish to show that $g(1+) = 1$, where $g(x) = f(1-f(2-x))$.

Pick any $\epsilon >0$. Take $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon).$ Pick any $x \in (1,1+\delta)$. We show that $|g(x)-1|< \epsilon$:

$$1< x <1+\delta \implies  1-\delta< 2-x < 1$$

Now $\delta \leq 1$, for any $t \in (1-\delta,1)$, $f(t)=-t$. Thus,

$$-1< f(2-x) < \delta-1 \implies 2-\delta< 1-f(2-x) < 2 $$

For any $t \in (2-\delta,2)$, $f(t)=t-1$. Thus,

$$1-\delta< g(x)= f(1-f(2-x)) < 1 \implies -\delta< g(x)-1 <0 \implies |g(x)-1|< \delta \leq \epsilon $$

Q.E.D.

---

**Proof of (2):** Write domain of $h$ and $g$ as $D(g)$ and $D(h)$ respectively. Also suppose $h(D(h))\subseteq D(g)$.

Pick any $\epsilon >0$. Since $\lim_{u \rightarrow h(c)^-} g(u) = M$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $u \in D(g)$,

$$\delta > h(c)-u > 0 \implies |g(u) - M|<\epsilon$$

$h$ is continuous at $c$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow c^+} h(x) = h(c)$. There is some $\eta > 0$ such that for all $x \in D(h)$,
$$\eta > x-c > 0 \implies |h(x) - h(c)|<\delta$$

With this $\eta$, we are done: Pick any $x \in D(h)$ such that $\eta > x-c > 0$. $h(x) \in D(g)$.

$x > c \implies h(x) < h(c)$. Then $0 < h(c)-h(x) < \delta$. Therefore, $|g(h(x)) - M| < \epsilon$.