# Finding the limit of a composite function graphically

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

Question :
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(1-f(2-x))$$

I'm having trouble understanding how to evaluate composite limits graphically when they aren't continuous. Could someone help me understand how to in a simpler way instead of explicitly stating the formula

Comment: I made an edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks!

Comment: As a remark, the same question was post in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260177/to-find-the-given-limits-from-the-graph/2260218#2260218. Perhaps the OP was not quite satisfied with my answer (sigh...

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(1-f(2-x))$$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(1-f(2-1-\epsilon))$$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(1-f(1-\epsilon))$$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(1+1-\epsilon)$$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(2-\epsilon)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Here,

lim(x->1+) f(1-f(2-x))

=lim(h->0+) f(1-f(2-1-h))
                 (Substituting x=1+h).

=lim(h->0+) f(1-f(1-h)).

Note from graph that  for x belonging to (0,1),         f(x)=-x.

Thus f(1-h)=-1+h.

Thus required limit

=lim(h->0+) f(1+1-h)

=lim(h->0+) f(2-h)

=1( from graph).

Comment: Please try to read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks@Rajat. I did not read this earlier. It was quite hard to express the mathematical forms without using proper notations.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as $x\to 1^{+}$, the variable $t=2-x\to 1^{-}$ and hence $u=f(t) \to -1^{+}$ (from graph). And then $z=1-u\to 2^{-}$ and thus finally $v=f(z) \to 1$ (from graph).

The expression $f(1-f(2-x))$ has been handled in a step by step manner by use of different variables starting with $t=2-x$ followed by introduction of $u, z, v$.

Also note that it is not necessary to guess the formula for $f(x) $ from graph (in this easy example it can be done because the graph consists of straight line segments). What is important is to notice that the graph gives information about left and right hand limits of $f$ at various points of interest like $-1,0,1,2$ and that is all we need to solve the problem here.